# Datasource Deploy Strategy SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a customer who has a production and development SQL Server database, but only one SSRS server with different folders for prod and dev reports. So same reports in each folder, but a set of reports in one folder points to prod data, and the reports in the other folder point to dev data. I deploy all the reports from BIDS using the "MYDATASOURCE_DEV" datasource, and then change all the shared and local datasets to use the  "MYDATASOURCE_PROD" datasource, change the deploy folder to the prod folder and deploy them. This is a pain since there are many datasets.

Is there a way to bulk change all the datasets, local and shared in a project? I have to have 2 datasources on the server, since there is only one server yet there is prod and dev data.

What is the best way to manage this?

Thanks...

Comment: I suppose I could open up all the rsd files in a text editor and replace all <DataSourceReference>MYDATASOURCE_DEV</DataSourceReference> with <DataSourceReference>MYDATASOURCE_DEV</DataSourceReference> and open up all rdl files and replace all <DataSourceName>MYDATASOURCE_DEV</DataSourceName> with <DataSourceName>MYDATASOURCE_PROD</DataSourceName> . Is that wise?

Comment: You can install a second instance of SSRS for Dev that mirrors your production environment. Then all you'll have to do is change your deployment path since the data source names will be the same in both environments.

Comment: I know that, but this customer won't do that.

Comment: Take a look at the following link. http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/86369/change-datasource-of-ssrs-report-with-powershell.html